# One-time binding throwing error with {{::photo.src}}

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a one-time binding in Angular. I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{::photo.src}}"/>
```

When the page loads, Angular throws this error:

```
Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [::photo.src] starting at [::photo.src]
```

I read in a few different places that this was likely due to a leading space in the expression... but as you can see, there's no leading space in my code. If I do add the leading space, I of course get the same error (but at column 2).

<del>I'm using version 1.3.10 of Angular, so I believe one-time binding is included.</del>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** it seems I was mistaken - I was actually using version 1.2.24, so one-time binding was not yet supported. Thanks to @sss for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One-time binding is supported since AngularJS 1.3.0.

Comment: Darn. Is 1.3.0-beta.10 not the same as 1.3.10? I checked https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.10/docs/guide/expression and it does cover one-time binding.

Comment: Ahh wait I just re-checked my angular file and it seems I was mistaken - I'm using 1.2.24. I'll update my question accordingly, thanks for the help!